# Add column to nested tables using outer value in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I have an outer table with "Name" and "Content" columns, I also have nested tables contained in the "Content" column

[image]

How do I add a new column in the nested tables using the value "Name" from the outer one?

[image]

If I add a new column in the outer using

```
= Table.AddColumn(Step-1,"NewColOut", each Table.AddColumn([Content],"FileName", (x)=> [Name]))
```

I have no problem, what if I want to transform "Content" without adding a new column in the outer one?

I tried Table.TransformColumns but to no avail, I am not able to bring in the "Name" value at the nested table level

any help would be greately appreciated

Comment: Please post sample data and query as text along with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to do this, since if you expand the embedded table, it will automatically copy down the filename, but if you wanted to, you could use the simple line

```
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStepNameGoesHere, "NewColOut", each let name=[Name] in  Table.AddColumn([Content],"Filename",each name))
```

or with transform

```
#"Added Custom1"= Table.FromRecords(Table.TransformRows(#"PriorStepNameGoesHere",
     (r) => Record.TransformFields(r,
     {"Content", each Table.AddColumn(_,"NewColOut",each r[Name]) })))
```

Comment: Yes you are right, my example was not good enough
Your suggestion adds a column to the outer table, I was wondering if it is possible to pass a value from it into the nested table using Table.TransformColumns

Comment: edited answer to use table transform